# Cordova app cannot load any files in assets/www (only index.html)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm compiling a very simple Cordova app and deploying on Android. I want to test the smoothness of jQuery Mobile on various Android devices, so I'm compiling an app with the contents of the jQuery Mobile demo folder.

I created a new Cordova project and placed the contents of jQuery Mobile demo folder into my `www` folder.

I then used the Cordova binary to add the android platform, ran cordova build, and finally `cordova run android`.

The application opened on my phone, but no files other than the `index.html` will load. I connected up the app to the Chrome Inspector debugger to see what wasn't loading, here's what I saw:

[image: Errors in debugger]

All of the files that Cordova can't find, do exist in `platforms/android/assets/www`. Cordova can find `index.html` just find, but it cannot load anything else.

If I open that folder in a web browser, everything loads just fine.

**Anyone know what could be causing this issue or what steps I might take to further troubleshoot and isolate the issue?** I've Googled for hours and I cannot find anyone else facing a situation quite like this. For other people, it's the `index.html` file that won't load or they simply forgot to add the files they want into the `www` folder. In my case, `index.html` loads fine, but nothing else will (see screenshot above).

Here is my `config.xml` (mostly just the standard default):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.rand.jqmdemo" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>jqmdemo</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="~4.1.1" />
</widget>
```

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.elliot.jqmdemo" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
</manifest>
```

Here is my `index.html` file: http://pastebin.com/duFSLT5T

Comment: That is not an cordova issue, that is an issue of your app. Please show your HTML file.

Comment: @Joerg Thanks for helping. This is my index.html file: http://pastebin.com/duFSLT5T it is unmodified from the jQuery Mobile demos folder. All of the relative file includes are valid and the index.html does load properly in a regular web browser.

Comment: On a side note; I have used jQuery Mobile with Phonegap / Cordova before at it was not HORRIBLY bad, but still pretty bad, especially with older phones (~year old). I would not use jQuery Mobile on any of my projects anymore, but instead I really like Intel AppFramework.

Comment: Are you sure, that the directory _assets exists? Not important, but why do you use js and _assets/js?

Comment: @Joerg Yep, they do exist, here's a screenshot of my www folder: http://pasteboard.co/26GVqv3.png (the files do exist within that folder). I can't comment on why it's structured that way because I'm merely copied and pasted the contents of jQuery Mobile's demo folder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I eventually figured this out. It's a Cordova issue while deploying with Android. Any folders that begin with an underscore are omitted without warning. It looks like the bug has been around for over 5 years and with no sign of getting fixed soon:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5343

Answer (score 1):

If your files are in documents->jqdemo->www , like you show on pasteboard.co, then your files are in the wrong place.

They have to be in:

> your_cordova_project->platforms->android->assets->www

To do so:

Include the assets, index.html, js only in the root folder of your cordova project and then do a cordova build and don't change the platform www folder by yourself.

If you are coding and not just testing, the better way is to have symlinks or pre-scripts, which do the copy job. So you don't have to call every time cordova build.

jQuery Mobile: It runs very well on mobile devices, **if** you know what you are doing. Otherwise it is very easy to slow down your app. So, be careful!

**Update:**

Interesting problem and I stay on it, that the path is not correct, maybe not resolvable. So, try this things:

1. Create a new css file, name test.css and content:

```css
body {
   background-color: red !important;
   font-size: 3em !important;
}
```

Put this file in the root of your www folder, link it in your html-file and make a cordova build. Do you see the file in the platform www-folder?

How does it affect on your device?

Comment: I appreciate your help! My code is already in that location. The screenshot I showed you earlier was simply the `www` folder where the source sits before it's built by Cordova for the Android platform. Here is a screenshot from my platforms->android->assets->www folder: http://pasteboard.co/29GStIj.png  All of the code and all files are there. Here's a screenshot of the location of the CSS file that Cordova can't find: http://pasteboard.co/29PGQKi.png